# How to get list elements by index in elixir

Tags: arrays, list, elixir

```
{status, body} = File.read("/etc/hosts")
if status == :ok do
    hosts = String.split body, "\n"
    hosts = Enum.map(hosts, fn(host) -> line_to_host(host) end)
else
    IO.puts "error reading: /etc/hosts"
end
```

I have the following elixir function where I read the /etc/hosts file and try to split it line by line using `String.split`.

Then I map through the line list of hosts and call line_to_host(host) for each. The line_to_host method splits the line by `" "` and then I want to set the `from` and `to` variable:

```
def line_to_host(line) do
    data = String.split line, " "
    from = elem(data, 0) // doesn't work
    to = elem(data, 1) // doesn't work either
    %Host{from: from, to: to}
end
```

I looked through stackoverflow, the elixir docs and googled about how to get an list element at a specific index.
I know there is `head/tail` but there has to be a better way of getting list elements.

`elem(list, index)` does exactly what I need but unfortunately it's not working with `String.split`.

How to get list/tuple elements by ID in elixir

Comment: You don t want to do `{status, body} = File.read("/etc/hosts")` followed by `if`. Prefer pattern matching: `case File.read("/etc/hosts") do {:ok, body} -> ...`

Comment: okay, good to know that. thanks mate.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use pattern matching for that:

```
[from, to] = String.split line, " "
```

Maybe you want to add `parts: 2` option to ensure you will get only two parts in case there is more than one space in the line:

```
[from, to] = String.split line, " ", parts: 2
```

There is also [`Enum.at/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#at/3), which would work fine here but is unidiomatic. The problem with `Enum.at` is that due to the list implementation in Elixir, it needs to traverse the entire list up to the requested index so it can be very inefficient for large lists.

---

*Edit: here's the requested example with `Enum.at`, but I would not use it in this case*

```
parts = String.split line, " "
from = Enum.at(parts, 0)
to = Enum.at(parts, 1)
```

Comment: I'm a bit unsatisfied by this solution. Isn't it possible to just get the X part of that String.split returns? Enum.at didn't work with String.split.

Comment: Enum.at should work just fine. I'll add an example to my answer. Keep in mind, it is very unidiomatic to use Enum.at in Elixir, if it can be solved otherwise.

Comment: How to make `Enum.map` from second item in array (i.e. skipping the first one)?

Comment: @W.M. I am not sure I understand your question correctly, it seems unrelated to this. You should probably post a new question with example input, expected output and what you have tried so far.

Comment: @PatrickOscity I meant how to loop through an object array skipping the first item (at position 0), i.e. `Enum.map` without the first item in the array.

Comment: @W.M. You can either do `[head | tail].= list` (If you need the first element, head, as well) or `tail = tl(list)` (if you don't need the head) to get the tail of a list, then just map over that.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider implementing a recursive function instead Enum.at. It would provide more performance. It depends on if you need a high-performance code, of course.

**Benchmarking:**

```
Comparison: 
Recursive Enum At        9.41 M
Native Enum At           6.48 M - 1.45x slower +48.05 ns
```

**Example code:**

```
defmodule Test do
  def enum_at([h | t] = x, i) when i > 0  do
    enum_at(t, i-1)
  end
  def enum_at([h | t], i), do: h
end

#[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] |> Test.enum_at(4)
# 5
```

***In your case:***

```
data = String.split line, " "
%Host{from: enum_at(data, 0), to: enum_at(data, 1)}
```

Pattern Matching could be the best option, but it could "fail" if the split returns a 3 elements list. You should add validations on both cases.